# c# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'

Tags: c#, casting

i cant find anything to fix this error :/ im trying to 2 letter combinations(ex. aa,ba,cb) to multiplier like(aa*3=4*3 ba*2=3,5*2). 
 my codes are;

```
string[] dersler = new string[9];
    double[] kredi = new double[9];
    double[] krediSonuclari = new double[9];

    double derscarp(double s1, double s2)
    {
        return s1 * s2;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int i=0;
        int j = 0;
        foreach (TextBox item in Controls)
        {
            if (item.Name.Substring(0,7)=="txtders")
            {
                dersler[i] = Convert.ToString(item.Text);
                i++;
            }
        }
        foreach (TextBox item in Controls)
        {
            if (item.Name.Substring(0, 8) == "txtkredi")
            {
                kredi[j] = Convert.ToDouble(item.Text);
                j++;
            }
        }

        double toplam =0;
        for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++)
        {
```

Comment: Have you tried to `Debug` the code? I mean running in `Debug` mode

Comment: The clue is in the error message...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
foreach (TextBox item in Controls)
```

`Controls` contains some controls that aren't textboxes.
Your `foreach` statement tells the compiler to cast each item in the collection to `TextBox`, which won't work.

Instead, you can call `.OfType<TextBox>()`, which will return a filtered subsequence of the collection that only contains `TextBox` instances.

Comment: Just to note this is in the System.Linq which is only available in .Net 3.5 and up.

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
foreach (TextBox item in Controls)
{
    if (item.Name.Substring(0,7)=="txtders")
    {
        dersler[i] = Convert.ToString(item.Text);
        i++;
    }
}
```

you assume every control in your form is a textbox, which is probably not true. Because of that it will try to cast your Label controls as a TextBox, fail and throw an error.

Try this instead:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Controls)
{
    TextBox item = ctrl as TextBox;
    if (item != null) 
    {
        if (item.Name.Substring(0,7)=="txtders")
        {
            dersler[i] = Convert.ToString(item.Text);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but i just get another error like "Input string was not in a correct format." i think i have to take more lessons about c# :/ thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
foreach (TextBox item in Controls) //implicit cast.

}
```

with

```
 foreach (Control ctrl in Controls)
     if (ctrl is TextBox){
         TextBox tb = (Textbox)ctrl; //explicit cast
     }
 }
```

foreach does not automagically pick out the cherr... ehm... Textboxes of the Control Collection, so for every CONTROL inside the collection, that is NOT a TextBox the implicit cast will fail.